# Backpack fileupload fails Laravel validation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7, laravel-backpack

I want to upload image to an existing item at the moment. These are the attributes of my field:

```
        [
            'label' => __('admin.product_image'),
            'name' => "product_image",
            'type' => 'image',
            'upload' => true,
            'disk' => 'uploads'
        ],
```

In my form request class:

```
        'product_image' => 'nullable|file',
```

If I swtich off validation and I dd my 'product_image' from request I get this:

https://prnt.sc/syx3ya

Please can someone help me to find what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backpack by default convert file to base64 string, and your file validator fails, because attribute contains string, not file.